# zapier unsubscribe webhook doesn't get called

Tags: zapier

I've created a new Zapier integration and it works okay so far. But when I turn of the Zap created using the integration, the unsubscribe webhook doesn't get called. For testing, I've used https://webhook.site as the unsubscribe url but it never gets called. Here's the code that shows in the unsubscribe code mode:

```
const options = {
  url: 'https://webhook.site/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'X-KEY': bundle.authData.key
  },
  params: {

  },
  body: {
    'hookUrl': bundle.subscribeData.id,
    'key': bundle.authData.key
  }
}

return z.request(options)
  .then((response) => {
    response.throwForStatus();
    const results = response.json;

    // You can do any parsing you need for results here before returning them

    return results;
  });
```